# Export svg and img elements to the same file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to export a svg and an img elements to the same file. I have already exported svg elements using JavaScript, but I did not manage to export both the image and the svg (I assume because the types/encodings of the two objects are different). What I tried was:

```
let downloadButton  = document.getElementById("button");
  downloadButton.onclick = function saveSvg() {
    let svgData = document.getElementsByClassName("chart")[0].outerHTML;
    let imgData = document.getElementById("img").outerHTML;
    let svgImgBlob = new Blob([svgData, imgData], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    let Url = URL.createObjectURL(svgImgBlob);
    let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = Url;
    downloadLink.download = "test";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
```

However, I get the following error message

> error on line 1 at column 4070: Extra content at the end of the document

The other idea I had was to draw the svg on a canvas, so that both are of the same type (I assume both are going to be), however, I was not fully sure if it would work, so I did not try it.

Is it even possible to export two different types of elements to the same file?

Link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jefo6wns/1/).

Comment: Any file is either an `svg`, or a `jpg`, or a `png`, etc. And your code seems to try to append the img *tag* (as opposed to the binary data).

Comment: This is how I export svgs, I simply create a Blob object from the outerHTML and export it. Could you elaborate a bit more on the binary data part?

Comment: The `svg` format is a vector format (descriptive text); all other images use binary (because it's a pixel format, compressed or no)